# Does anyone know how to successfully transition a vanilla Javascript app into an Node Express app so that it can deploy on Heroku?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax, heroku

I'm new to programming and I have a client-side Javascript app that utilizes an AJAX request in order to communicate with a chatbot. I have API keys that I hide, and when I run my app locally it works, but when I push to Heroku it doesn't recognize the variables even when I make Heroku think my app is a PHP one (since it's natively in JS and Heroku doesn't deploy static sites). Thus, I'm trying to configure it as a Node project so that I'm able to set environment variables.

Full description below, I hope it's detailed enough. Appreciate the assistance.

My package.json

```js
  "name": "ask-randy",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "Capstone",
  "main": "lib/index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "nodemon lib/index.js",
    "build": "./node_modules/webpack/bin/webpack.js",
    "test": "./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha --compilers js:babel-core/register"
  },
  "repository": {
    "type": "git",
    "url": "git+https://github.com/turingschool-examples/game-time-starter-kit-FEm1.git"
  },
  "author": "Ashish Vaid",
  "license": "MIT",
  "bugs": {
    "url": "https://github.com/turingschool-examples/quantified-self-starter-kit/issues"
  },
  "homepage": "https://github.com/turingschool-examples/quantified-self-starter-kit#readme",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.5.2",
    "babel-core": "^6.18.2",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.7",
    "babel-preset-env": "^1.6.0",
    "chai": "^3.5.0",
    "chromedriver": "^2.27.2",
    "css-loader": "^0.26.0",
    "jquery": "^3.1.1",
    "mocha": "^3.1.2",
    "mocha-loader": "^1.0.0",
    "node-libs-browser": "^1.0.0",
    "node-sass": "^4.3.0",
    "nodemon": "^1.14.7",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "selenium-webdriver": "^3.0.1",
    "style-loader": "^0.13.1",
    "webdriverjs": "^1.7.5",
    "webpack": "^1.14.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^1.16.2"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "dotenv": "^4.0.0",
    "env2": "^2.2.0",
    "express": "^4.16.2",
    "jsdom": "^11.5.1"
  }
}
```

My index.html (living in the root of my app)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Ask Randy</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="./lib/stylesheets/styles.css">
<link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lobster|Raleway:400,200' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
  </head>

<header class="cf">
    <nav>
       <h1 class="logo">Ask Randy</h1>
    </nav>
 </header>

<br>
  <body>
    <div class="text-container">

      <div class="container">
        <img src="./images/randy_profile.png" alt="Avatar">
        <p>I'm Randy the Ask Randy Chatbot, you can ask me anything you know what I'm sayin.</p>
        <span class="time-right"></span>
      </div>
    </div>



<br>
    <div class="wrapper748 center padding-40 tablet-padding">

  <!-- Comment Form Start -->
  <!-- <div class="row shadow padding-15 white"> -->

    <!-- <form class="form wire teal"> -->
      <textarea rows="4" cols="110" placeholder="say something..."></textarea>

      <!-- Submit Start -->
      <div class="row pull-left -margin padding-top-10">
        <!-- <span class="btn fill-transparent text-gray hover-disable -padding-left"></span> -->
        <button class="btn teal pull-right">Submit</button>     <button class="btn red pull-right" type="reset" value="Reset">Clear Chat History</button>

      </div>
      <!-- Submit End -->
    <!-- </form> -->

<div class="lawrence-randy">
  <img class="randy-pic" src="./images/lawrence_randy.png" alt="randy-pic">
</div>


<script type='text/javascript' src='config.js'></script>
<script src="main.bundle.js"></script>

  </body>
</html>
```

My index.js (in place of server.js typical of Node apps).

```js
var express = require('express')
var app  = express()
var path = require('path');
require('dotenv').config()
var appRoot = process.env.PWD
console.log(appRoot)

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000)

app.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.sendFile(appRoot + '/index.html');
});


if(!module.parent) {
  app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
    console.log("App is running on " + app.get('port') + ".")
  })
}

// const myAppId = config.APP_ID
// const myKey = config.USER_KEY

const randyAjaxRequests = require('./ajax-requests/chat-requests')
const randyResponseHandlers = require('./response-handlers/chat-responses')
const randyEventListeners = require('./event-listeners/chat-listeners')


// export{myAppId, myKey}
```

I'm doing some DOM manipulation after I return my AJAX and I know I have to make some adjustments when doing Jquery in Node, but I can't even get the local environment to render my assets(CSS, JS).

I get an error in the console like this:

```js
ERROR in ./~/raw-body/~/iconv-lite/encodings/tables/gb18030-ranges.json
Module parse failed: /Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/raw-body/node_modules/iconv-lite/encodings/tables/gb18030-ranges.json Unexpected token (1:9)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
SyntaxError: Unexpected token (1:9)
    at Parser.pp$4.raise (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:2221:15)
    at Parser.pp.unexpected (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:603:10)
    at Parser.pp.semicolon (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:581:61)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseExpressionStatement (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:966:10)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:730:24)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseBlock (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:981:25)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseStatement (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:709:33)
    at Parser.pp$1.parseTopLevel (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:638:25)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:516:17)
    at Object.parse (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/acorn/dist/acorn.js:3098:39)
    at Parser.parse (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/webpack/lib/Parser.js:902:15)
    at DependenciesBlock.<anonymous> (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/webpack/lib/NormalModule.js:104:16)
    at DependenciesBlock.onModuleBuild (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:310:10)
    at nextLoader (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:275:25)
    at /Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/webpack-core/lib/NormalModuleMixin.js:259:5
    at Storage.finished (/Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/enhanced-resolve/lib/CachedInputFileSystem.js:38:16)
    at /Users/vaidashi/turing/4module/projects/ask-randy/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js:78:16
    at FSReqWrap.readFileAfterClose [as oncomplete] (fs.js:447:3)
 @ ./~/raw-body/~/iconv-lite/encodings/dbcs-data.js 106:37-76
```

This is the error when I open up my Chrome developer tools: 
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yNRCI.png)